# How to change position of text in Maya Python

Tags: python, user-interface, maya

I am making gui in maya using python but i am new in that and i Don't know how to change positions of text in maya using python.

**Code:**

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

# Make a new window

window = cmds.window( title="Render", iconName='BTD', widthHeight=
(500,500),titleBar=True,minimizeButton=True,maximizeButton=True )
cmds.columnLayout( adjustableColumn=True)

form = cmds.formLayout()
tabs = cmds.tabLayout(innerMarginWidth=10, innerMarginHeight=10)
cmds.formLayout(form,edit=True,attachForm=((tabs, 'top', 0), (tabs, 'left', 
0), (tabs, 'bottom', 0), (tabs, 'right', 0)) )
child1 = cmds.rowColumnLayout(numberOfColumns=2)
cmds.button(label='1')
cmds.button(label='2')
cmds.button(label='3')  
cmds.setParent( '..' )


child2 = cmds.rowColumnLayout(numberOfColumns=1)
cmds.text("Output Directory",width = 50,height=50,font = "boldLabelFont")
cmds.text("Notify on job completion",width = 200,height=50,font = 
"boldLabelFont")
cmds.setParent( '..' )


child3 = cmds.rowColumnLayout(numberOfColumns=2)
cmds.button(label='7')
cmds.button(label='8')
cmds.button(label='9')
cmds.setParent( '..' )

cmds.tabLayout( tabs, edit=True, tabLabel=((child1, 'General'), (child2, 
'Advanced'),(child3, 'Job Software')) )
cmds.setParent( '..' )

cmds.showWindow( window )
```

**Output**

[image]

**Expected Output**

[image]

There are any concept like give x axis and y axis to text ?

Please tell me how to do formatting in maya using python

Answer (score 2):

It is just the `align` attribute you have to add and it accepts one of `left`, `right` and `center`. If you don't set it, by default it is `center`

```
   cmds.text("Output Directory",width=50, height=50,font="boldLabelFont", align='left')
```

Comment: i want to make submit button outside the tab layout  how to do that  ?

Comment: align =left will push the text to extreme left but i want to print 2 space and then text. is there are any concept like x axis and y axis ?

Comment: I normally try to use `cmds.window` as it's not so flexible, if you want to `indent` you can just use empty space as '    Output Directory' or a tab `\tOutput Directory`